# Visual Studio Code editor icons

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for the default icons featured in the activity bar, status bar and panel included in VSCode but I cannot find them anywhere. Does anyone know if and where i can get a hold of them?

[image: Activity bar]

[image: Panel]

[image: Status bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Command Palette `cmd+option+p` and look for `Inspect Context Keys`, it will enable you to inspect those icons via the integrated dev tool. You can then copy the correspondent SVG code for each icon.

If you are simply looking for nice looking icons in `png`, `psd` or `eps` for your project, [flaticon.com](https://www.flaticon.com/) is a good place to go. Just search for the corresponding icons names ('documents', 'zoom', 'git', 'bug'...).